# Convert curl with --form to python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a functioning curl request:

```
curl --form "bio[0]=@images/12345.jpg" --form "bio[1]=@images/6789.jpg" --form "Verify=Verfiy" http://192.45.35.89/test.php
```

that I'm trying to convert to python requests:

```
requests.post('http://192.45.35.89/test.php', data = {
    'bio' : [
        ('12345.jpg', open('images/12345.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/png'),
        ('6789.jpg', open('images/6789.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/png')
    ],
    'Verify' : 'Verify'
})
```

The python version of the request yields a server error about "files not found or not accessible".

Am I correctly transforming the curl request to python requests? Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to send the files in a `files` dictionary to send the data as multipart/form-data as curl does:

```
requests.post('http://192.45.35.89/test.php', 
    files = {
        'bio[0]' : ('12345.jpg', open('images/12345.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/png'),
        'bio[1]' : ('6789.jpg', open('images/6789.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/png')
    },
    data = {'Verify' : 'Verify'})
```

Reference: [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)